# List Files in a Dictory and store user choice

Tags: php, html

I'm fairly new to php and html in general. I am working on a pop up window that list files within a subdirectory, allow user to select only one and then sends it to a c program through the use of a submit button.

The problem is that I don't know how to allow user to select a file from a list and store said selection in a variable.

The other two requirements is that:
- The c program is in the parent directory
- The only files to be listed are .txt files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Test</h1>
<select name="test">
<?php
$dir="./files";

if (is_dir ($dir))
{
    if ($dh = opendir($dir))
    {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) != false)
        {
             if ($file != ".." && $file != "." && strtolower(substr($file,strrpos($file,'.') +1)) == 'txt)
              {
                   echo "option value =\"$file\"> $file </option>";
               }
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>

<button = type="button" onclick="self.close()"> Cancel </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for ideas on how to implement this....

**Edit:** Added in what I tried to do. The part I'm trying to figure out is is: get selected value from drop list box, send to submit button. Not sure how to go from this. Probably from a lack of understanding.

FYI, Sorry for not putting in the code before.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried

Comment: glob() for file list then a form for selection .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.Pretty straightforward. Now I feel like an idiot. Thank you for your time.

```
<form action="example.php" method="POST">
<select name="test" id="test">
<?php
$dir="./files";

if (is_dir ($dir))
{
    if ($dh = opendir($dir))
    {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) != false)
        {
             if ($file != ".." && $file != "." &&  strtolower(substr($file,strrpos($file,'.') +1)) == 'txt)
               {
                   echo "option value =\"$file\"> $file </option>";
               }
        }
     }
}
?>
</select>
<input type="Submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Comment: If you answered your own question, mark it as answered